# Carousel add active jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can I add the active carousel class in the .slider-item of the html, that is, have the same active and deactivated handling?

HTML:

```
      <div class="client-img-wrapper">
        <div class="slider-item"></div>
        <div class="slider-item"></div>
        <div class="slider-item"></div>
      </div>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://reduan.net/slider_01.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://reduan.net/slider_02.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://reduan.net/slider_03.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

CSS:

```
.slider-item {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slider-item.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

LINK: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQqbYG

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same active and deactivated handling"?

Comment: Add the active class to the slider-item, according to the carousel's active

Comment: Add class to .client-img-wrapper first child: https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: It is not the first selector, but as the bootstrap carousel is activated, the active class must be added in the custom slider

Comment: @Hendrix do you have a design so that we can try to see what you want to achieve here?